# Vaadin 7 + EJB integration (How to inject stateful bean to servlet)

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, ejb, vaadin

I would like to integrate Vaadin 7 with J2EE EJB, but I have a problem, that I am not able to lookup stateful bean from servlet. I read a tutorial, that gives an advice, how to make this integration with CDI, but I don't want to use CDI.

So I rewrite the tutorial like this. But lookup service does not find my stateful bean - MyVaadinUI. Could someone pleas help me? What is wrong with my code? I am not sure if I need some special config files in WAR module like ejb-jar.xml? Becouse I dont have any. My apps consists of EAR module and EJB - where is just UserBean and WAR module, where is this class and jee6UiProveder. Thanks

```
package cz.simon.webmailapp.web;


@Theme("mytheme")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Stateful
@LocalBean
public class MyVaadinUI extends UI{

@EJB
private UserBean bean;

@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true, 
initParams = { 
    @WebInitParam(name = "UIProvider", value = "cz.simon.webmailapp.web.Jee6UIProvider") })
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MyVaadinUI.class, widgetset = "cz.simon.webmailapp.web.AppWidgetSet")
public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {




public UI getUI() {

        Context jndi = null;
        UI ui = null;
        try {
            jndi = new InitialContext();
             ui = (UI) jndi.lookup("java:module/MyVaadinUI");
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyVaadinUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


     return ui;
}
}

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    bean.setUser("Test");
    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setMargin(true);
    setContent(layout);

    Button button = new Button(bean.getUser() + "Click Me!!!");
    button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            layout.addComponent(new Label("Thank you for clicking"));
        }
    });
    layout.addComponent(button);
}
```

}

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Would you mind to explain why you don't want to use CDI? Using session beans in the WAR module of the EAR seems not ideal to me and could be the problem.

Comment: You seem to be mixing UI and controller components altogether... you should try to respect MVC...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are doing it right. you have to either use CDI for UI for injecting EJBs or do a lookup for beans explicitly. As you dont want to use CDI for your UI Class the only option left for you is to use look up.

```
 @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
       try {
          //TODO Create a getter method that returns you the JNDI name of the bean
          userBean = (UserBean) lookup(getJNDINameOfUserBean());
        } catch (NamingException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }  
       //TODO do other Stuff.
    }

    private Object lookup(String jndiName) throws NamingException{
      if(null==context){
        initContext();
      }
       return  context.lookup(jndiName);

    }

   private void initContext() throws NamingException{
      //Set properties if any and initialize the context
      // Class level variable for Context
      context = new InitialContext();   
   }
```